# Open htaccess password protectected page with no prompts

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a directory on a website that is password protected via htaccess.  I want to be able to open this web page through my application without having the user enter the password but rather do it programatically.

For instance, is there a way I can embed the login information in the URL?  Such as http://www.mypage.com/page.html?htaccesspassword=asdasdas

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scheme://username:password@host/path
```

Comment: How to use this? It still asks for password.

Comment: This format doesn't work with any IE since IE6, when it was removed as a spoofing risk. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

Comment: I don't believe this works in Safari

Answer (score 1):

Although I think that authentication through the URL, as described by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, is much simpler, another approach might be setting the `Authorization` header.

I'm assuming you're using Basic authentication.

The `Authorization` header looks something like this:

> Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedCredentials

Where `Base64EncodedCredentials` is the username and password encoded with the Base 64 algorithm in the format

> username:password

More information about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication