# using qrcode to login a website php

Tags: php, android, qr-code

I am thinking of making a Login system where a user enters their username, password and scans a QR code which is then sent to a PHP page.

I would then use those credentials to authenticate the user.

I have a PHP login page and an android application to scan a QR code but do not know how to link them.

Also does anyone know if this has been done before?

Comment: What do you mean by you "do not know how to link them"? The steps described in the article you linked in your comment below seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Have a login page that uses HTTP authentication and then [put the username and password in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780656/open-htaccess-password-protectected-page-with-no-prompts).

Comment: I'm not sure this answers how to send the QR code to the server.

Comment: You can't "send the QR code to the server". You make the QR code contain the credentials you need in order to log in.

Comment: I imagined from the wording of the question the QR code was supposed to be an extra security feature, but I guess it could be either.

Comment: i need some thing like that plugin http://www.jackreichert.com/2012/01/22/no-more-passwords-log-into-wordpress-using-a-qr-code/